# Install Ubuntu Touch on Cheap ARM A8 Chip Tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I was gifted an Le Pan TC 970 tablet (it was on sale and couldn't be passed up).
It is OMAP3, single core ARM A8, 500MB RAM & 1 GHz.
Would Ubuntu Touch be able to be installed, or even Kubuntu with plasma mobile?

Or, is this just a low end tablet that will remain as is?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think OMAP3 is directly supported for Ubuntu-Touch. 

<opinion>
However OMAP3 linux kernel is  community supported and does boot somewhat recent Linux kernels and Android on BeagleBoard so I would think that it may work since the ubuntu-touch reuses a lot of Android guts. I have not tried this myself since I don't have one of these, so take this answer with a grain of salt.

</opinion>